# To make the same size of html input button and uploaded file control browse button

Tags: html, file-upload

Is there any way to make the same size of html input button and uploaded file control browse button?
When I make changes in size of html input button, it affects to the horizontal alignment of these buttons?

Thanks
Aung

Answer (score 0):

This relies on the browser and cannot be changed without javascript (re-doing the elements for instance).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change the look and feel of basic object. To achieve this, you can create custom server side control in which you achieve the desired look by overriding the render.